# What makes a song not sound like classical music

Tags: classical-music, melody, genre

For example [La Califfa](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=EdNSQiP1CHs), it is sung by a mezzo-soprano but the melody of this song cannot be mistaken for classical music. Is there a way to explain this? What exactly makes it sound modern?

Comment: Hi! It's an intriguing question, but it has problems as a Stack Exchange question. For one thing, questions about listening to and responding to a song are usually a better fit at [MusicFans SE](https://musicfans.stackexchange.com/). But anywhere, there are some problems with the way of talking about it that make it mostly an opinion-based question. For one, people rarely agree on what "counts" as "classical" music. (There's a historical *period* called "Classical," like Mozart, but people usually mean a category of music that isn't pop, rock, jazz, etc.)...

Comment: IMO, the premise of the question is problematic. To my ear, the song doesn't sound modern at all — it sounds like a throwback to the Romantic era of classical music, although not an especially sophisticated one. I agree with @AndyBonner — as currently written, the question doesn't fit this site well. Maybe edit it to describe why it doesn't sound classical to you and then ask for some analysis?

Comment: ... and of course it's equally unclear what the "opposite of classical" is. You use the word "modern," but sometimes that's used for "classical" music written in the 20th century or later. The track in question is from a movie soundtrack, and that's one of the places that people disagree the most about whether it should be considered "classical" or not. So in short, I encourage you to keep thinking along the lines of "why does this song sound the way it does," but to avoid trying to define its genre.

Comment: (Some helpful follow-up questions to "why does this sound the way it does" are often "Which instruments are used," "What do the tempo and rhythm do," "What key/mode is it in," and "what does the 'volume' ('dynamics') do."

Comment: We have answered a number of "what elements identify this genre" questions. There's [a list on our Meta](https://music.meta.stackexchange.com/a/3581/70803) you could browse through as models.

Comment: To the general public, violins, no drum beat, singing with vibrato, etc. sound like "classical" music. Many might call this song classical, or at least say it sounds like opera. Right or wrong, many will hear it that way.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis But the musicians way of telling if something is classical would be in fact: Does it have phrasing?

Comment: @Lazy, other styles - chant, Renaissance, jazz, rock, etc. etc. - have phrasing.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I do not think the OP meant *classical* in the sense of *music from the viennese classical period*. Jazz phrasing does exist but is quite a different thing from what would be considered phrasing from a classical viewpoint. And this is not downplaying anything, I love both classical music and classic jazz. But I’d say if there is one clear difference between the worlds it is phrasing. For the rest – the boundaries between these things have gotten rather thin.

Comment: @Jiu. Don't know why this was closed, it's just a matter of understanding the detail of classical style, and then applying a comparison to this song. For me, it's the initial (lack of) figuration in the string section. Classical style would do _something_ even just a pulse on a repeated tone. (Compare slow movements in Mozart horn concertos.) Later, like here https://youtu.be/EdNSQiP1CHs?t=40, the harmony is pop, not classical. You don't even need to get to the singing to know it isn't classical. You could pick other elements, but those stand out to me.

Comment: @Lazy, maybe vote to reopen so all this can go into answers.

Comment: @MichaelCurtis I’m not at the reputation to vote reopen here at Music SE. While your points about complexity and harmony are of course very good remarks, I’d still say this could (modulo some parts) be seen as somewhat classical romantic stuff (though as Aaron stated not particularly sophisticated one). But what gives this away as pop for me is the immediate lack of phrasing, of differentation of dynamic, rhythm and intensity, articulation, such stuff. And of course the style of mixing.

Comment: By classical music I mean the pieces that we learn in lyrical singing, antique arias, baroque, the classical period, romantic era and something after that like poulenc, satie...

Comment: I find la Califfa pleasing to the ear, rather direct, and the interval of "solo" in the phrase "Ha visto in me solo una cagna che" sounds distinct to me.

Comment: @Jiu Thanks for asking, and for continuing to comment. Two things: 1) To get the question re-opened, please edit the question itself, not just add comments. 2) For me at least, I still don't see how this could become a valid question. You would have to make it less about this song in particular and more about general matters; discussing and appreciating individual songs is best done at musicfans.stackexchange. And since it's clear that you mean "classical" in the broad sense rather than a historical period, any "what makes something classical" question would be impossibly opinion-based.